# Identities involving addition, subtraction and absolute value

Tags: computational-complexity, absolute-value, computability

**Questions:**

Q1: Is there any intuition behind the following "ugly" identity?
$$\forall x,y,z\in\mathbb{R},\text{if}\;x+y+z=0,\text{then}\;|x+|y|-z|+|x-y+|z||-x-2|x|-|y|-|z|=0$$
A more symmetrical form can be obtained by swapping and averaging but I don't see the necessity.

Q2: Given an expression involving only addition, subtraction and absolute value of real numbers, is there any *quick* way to verify whether it is identical to zero, instead of brutely checking all the possible outcomes of absolute values?

Q3: Would there be any mechanism able to generating *all* the identities involving only addition, subtraction and absolute value of real numbers, or at least *some* of them? For example, if we can lexically encode these expressions, we may be able to list one-by-one all the expressions and then pick out those which are identities...

Q4: It is easily to see its connection to the [SAT problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem), are they equivalent?

**Background:**

This question was inspired by the following function:
$$f_r(v,w)=\max{(v-r,\min{(v+r,w}))},$$
where $r\in\mathbb{R}^+$ can be thought as the parameter of the function and $v,w\in\mathbb{R}$ are the two inputs.
I was asked to check that $f_r(v,f_r(v,w))=f_r(v,w)$ and it was trivial. I noticed that
$$\max{(a,\min{(b,w}))}-\min{(b,\max{(a,w}))}=\left\{\begin{aligned}&a-b,&a\geq b\\&0,&a<b\end{aligned}\right.$$
It is also easy to check this but when I rewrite the min/max function using absolute values, the identity seems less apparent.